# How to divide a row by one of three counts depending on what its called?

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

So the query is that I have three different stores, I have a bunch of products in each store and I want to calculate the percentage of the product compared to the total number of products in that store. So with three stores I have three different total number of products that I want to divide the products by depending on what store they are in. However what ends up happening is that the Query divides every product by the first store value, how do I get it to specify which value to divide by depending on the store using this query if possible?

Image of my current table using this query.
[image: Image of my current table using this query.]

```
SELECT 
ss.name,
b.name,
y1.number,
(SUM(svs.facings) / y1.number) * 100 AS SecondaryPercentage
FROM
report.scene_visit_summary svs
    LEFT JOIN
static.stores ss ON svs.store_fk = ss.pk
    LEFT JOIN
static.template t ON svs.template_fk = t.pk
    LEFT JOIN
static_new.product p ON svs.product_fk = p.pk
    LEFT JOIN
static_new.brand b ON p.brand_fk = b.pk
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    SUM(svs.facings) AS number
FROM
    report.scene_visit_summary svs
LEFT JOIN static.stores ss ON svs.store_fk = ss.pk
LEFT JOIN static.template t ON svs.template_fk = t.pk
LEFT JOIN static_new.product p ON svs.product_fk = p.pk
LEFT JOIN static_new.brand b ON p.brand_fk = b.pk
WHERE
    session_uid IN ('**********************' , '**********************', 
'**********************')
GROUP BY ss.name) AS y1 ON y1.number
WHERE
session_uid IN ('**********************' , '**********************',
    '**********************')
    AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Main%'
GROUP BY b.name
```